# Android, detect COM port from keyPress

Tags: java, android, keyboard, serial-port, usb

I'm making an Android application (5.1.1).

On my device, I have 2 keyboards connected by 2 USB ports.

I have an handler on the Enter keyEvent :

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
{
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
    {
        //some action
    }

    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

I want to know from which Keyboard my event is sent.

How can I do that ? With COM Port ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `event.getDeviceId()` to differentiate between the two devices...
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#getDeviceId()